# cordova - can I upload IPA to testflight with out sdk?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working on a cordova/ios/android project that was developed by another dev before me, they were using testflight to distribute beta IPA to the client.

but it creates many issues when I try to upgrade different components.

1. Is it possible to upload to testflight with out integrating the SDK into the project? if yes then how?
2. What is testflight and why do I need to integrate it into the code?
3. what are the minimum steps to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at

https://www.testflightapp.com/

but I've got to agree that their information is a little sparse.

You can distribute an application through Testflight without putting their SDK into the code.
All you get without the SDK is distribution of the app.  If you do integrate the SDK you can get information about how the app is used and you can get application crashes.

The minimum is to

- Sign up on the testflight website as a developer (so you can distribute
  builds).
- Log in.
- Go to https://www.testflightapp.com/dashboard/ there
  is good documentation available from there.
- Build an archive of your app to get the ipa file -- preferably an ad-hoc distribution build.
- Add an app to your list of apps.
- Upload the app.
- Test install it yourself on one of your devices.
- Invite the beta testers (or maybe you have a list of the devices and entered them as being able to run your app because they have been doing it this way).

There is adequate documentation on the website.  If you don't want to add the SDK just ignore all that.  I've done this (without the SDK) so it can't be that hard.