# Can you upload .ipa files to Testflight without Mac?

Tags: phonegap-build, testflight

I am using Phonegap Build to quickly deploy and test my applications. For this to work, I had to go through an elaborated tutorial on creating provision files and certificates and borrow a Mac to make use of Keychain. By then however, I only registered one device UDID.

Now I want to add more devices, but I dont want to go through the whole process again, also what if I have to add other devices later?

So I was thinking to use Testflight, which only requires that you upload an .ipa file (apart from having a developers account etc). With Phonegap Build you can easily create these .ipa files.

However, since I am working with Windows, I dont see how I can upload the .ipa files on Testflight. Most tutorials online talk about using Xcode and some other Mac program.

Is there any way to upload it anyway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832592/cordova-can-i-upload-ipa-to-testflight-with-out-sdk

Comment: Yes thank you. But it looks it has changed since Apple's takeover?

Comment: @RRahmouni the old TestFlight app website is not available anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacks might be available but since Apple integrated TestFlight into iTunes Connect - which (at this time) does not have a public API - the only official solution is to use Xcode or Application Launcher for ipa uploads. Both are only available for OS X.

An alternative solution might be to use an iOS CI/CD (continuous integration and delivery) service to do the upload. We happen to have one - [bitrise.io](https://www.bitrise.io), CTO here - but you can find a couple of other services as well.